# Derivation of 'at most' equivalence in natural deduction

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I teach an intro logic class. One intuitive way of translating 'there is at most one F' is

$(\forall x)(Fx \rightarrow (\forall y)(Fy \rightarrow x=y))$

A student came up with the following, which is equivalent  and much more compact

$(\exists x)(\forall y)(Fy \rightarrow x=y)$

We can demonstrate equivalence via interderivability in a Fitch-style system:

$(\forall x)(Fx \rightarrow (\forall y)(Fy \rightarrow x=y)) \dashv \vdash (\exists x)(\forall y)(Fy \rightarrow x=y)$

Below are two derivations. Right to Left is pretty easy and short. Left to Right (second) is long and a bit of a bear. Here is the question: can that one be simplified, is there a more elegant derivation? I would like to help the less sophisticated students see the equivalence. *Actually I found a shorter, clearer derivation.* See below.

R to L
[Right to Left Derivation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqVrU.png)

L to R
[Left to Right Derivation, can this be shortened?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWi5P.png)

L to R Shorter
[L to R Shorter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcKek.png)

Comment: Yes, if you include the use of *derived rules*, (QN, MT, Imp, et cetera) you will have a shorter proof.

Comment: Two comments. First: How short you can make your proof depends on what rules you have. Theoretically, we could have a rule that formalizes this very inference and thus have a 1 step proof.  Second: shorter proofs do not necessarily make things more clear. For example, the theoretical 1 step proof from my first comment doesn't make things clear at all. But, I would also argue that your second, shorter, proof, is far less clear in explaining why the student's expression follows from your expression. I think the first proof that considers the two cases maket is far more clear.